# Google Apps Script, searching using a date

Tags: google-apps-script

I've never really coded before, so I'm sorry if this is a basic question/if I can't word this properly. Tried to google on my own but I'm pretty sure I'm searching the wrong terms.  So I'm making a Date Entry form in Google Sheets. The Form Sheet is where the form is, and the Data sheet is where the data inputted in the Form will be transferred to once the user hits the save button. Cell B2 in the form sheet is where users will input the date. B2 then gets save in the first column, the rest of the data in the Form will be saved in the same row. My goal is to allow B2 to also be used as a search box. Users can search for that date and the Form will repopulate with all the data in the same row as that date. My rationale is to allow users to edit some data on that date if they realize there were mistakes. Currently, if B2 is not a date (e.g. 1111, wwww) the form repopulates. But if it is a date, the form remains empty.

```
var SEARCH_COL_IDX = 0;
function Search() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var formS = ss.getSheetByName("Form");

var str = formS.getRange("B2").getValue();
var values = ss.getSheetByName("Data").getDataRange().getValues();
for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
  var row = values[i];
  if(row[SEARCH_COL_IDX] == str) {
                formS.getRange("B6").setValue(row[1]);
                formS.getRange("B7").setValue(row[2]);
                formS.getRange("B8").setValue(row[3]);
```

The data are all supposed to be numbers, but I made them characters for now because I was making sure the correct cell in Data form is going to the correct cell in the Form sheet and vice versa.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your situation. So `row[SEARCH_COL_IDX]` and `str` are supposed to be two dates, and you have problems checking whether they are the same date? In that case, `same date` would refer to the exact same date (day and time), or just same day? Also, are they dates or strings? (it could probably be useful if you could provide a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on).

Comment: Sorry! I tried clarifying in the comments but it became too long so I edited my question instead. I hope I'm a bit clearer. I've also linked the google sheet. So row[SEARCH_COL_IDX] is supposed to be the date save in the Data sheet, and STR is supposed to be the date from the Form Sheet. If they are the same date, cells from the Form sheet will be repopulated with data from the Data sheet in the same row as where SEARCH_COL_IDX is. @Iamblichus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check whether two dates are the same, you cannot do that directly with an [equality operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators#equality_operators). There are several ways to compare this. For example, you could use [Date.getTime()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime), or [Date.valueOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/valueOf).

For example, you could do:

```
if (row[SEARCH_COL_IDX].getTime() === str.getTime()) {
  // ...
}
```

#### Related:

- [Compare two dates with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript)

Comment: Oh! Thank you very much for the answer!